# FCGX_Accept_r fails with -88 return code

Tags: c, sockets, fastcgi

I am writing a fastcgi app in c++ and am struggling with FCGX_Accept_r() exiting without blocking with return value of "-88". After doing lots of googling I found out that you have to properly init FCGX structs, correct umask on the uds socket, don't forget to FCGX_Init() and check return code of FCGX_Init() and FCGX_InitRequest().

I've done all above for my program and still result is the same.

So i have tried to build the example C app from fcgi site here: http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/examples/threaded.c
 and it exited immediately.

The strange thing is that they don't have any sockets open there. So i have added a couple of lines - print out FCGX_Accept_() return value and open a uds socket.

Here is the resulting code:

```
/*
 * threaded.c -- A simple multi-threaded FastCGI application.
 */

#ifndef lint
static const char rcsid[] = "$Id: threaded.c,v 1.9 2001/11/20 03:23:21 robs Exp $";
#endif /* not lint */

#include "fcgi_config.h"

#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#ifdef HAVE_UNISTD_H
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include "fcgiapp.h"


#define THREAD_COUNT 20

static int counts[THREAD_COUNT];

static void *doit(void *a)
{
    int rc, i, thread_id = (int)a;
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    FCGX_Request request;
    char *server_name;

    FCGX_InitRequest(&request, 0, 0);

    for (;;)
    {
        static pthread_mutex_t accept_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
        static pthread_mutex_t counts_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

        /* Some platforms require accept() serialization, some don't.. */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&accept_mutex);
        rc = FCGX_Accept_r(&request);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&accept_mutex);

        if (rc < 0) {
        printf("failed accept: %d\n", rc);
            break;
    }

        server_name = FCGX_GetParam("SERVER_NAME", request.envp);

        FCGX_FPrintF(request.out,
            "Content-type: text/html\r\n"
            "\r\n"
            "<title>FastCGI Hello! (multi-threaded C, fcgiapp library)</title>"
            "<h1>FastCGI Hello! (multi-threaded C, fcgiapp library)</h1>"
            "Thread %d, Process %ld<p>"
            "Request counts for %d threads running on host <i>%s</i><p><code>",
            thread_id, pid, THREAD_COUNT, server_name ? server_name : "?");

        sleep(2);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&counts_mutex);
        ++counts[thread_id];
        for (i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++)
            FCGX_FPrintF(request.out, "%5d " , counts[i]);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&counts_mutex);

        FCGX_Finish_r(&request);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    pthread_t id[THREAD_COUNT];

    FCGX_Init();

    umask(0);
    FCGX_OpenSocket("/tmp/fcgi.sock", 10);

    for (i = 1; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++)
        pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, doit, (void*)i);

    doit(0);

    return 0;
}
```

And guess what:

```
# gcc fcgi.c -lpthread -lfcgi         
# ./a.out
failed accept: -88
failed accept: -88
failed accept: -88
failed accept: -88
failed accept: -88
failed accept: -88
failed accept: -88
failed accept: -88
failed accept: -88
failed accept: -88
failed accept: -88
failed accept: -88
failed accept: -88
failed accept: -88
failed accept: -88
failed accept: -88
failed accept: -88
failed accept: -88
failed accept: -88
failed accept: -failed accept: -88
```

Could anyone please point out what am I doint wrong?
Thank you!

**Update:**

Interesting thing is that example from here https://habrahabr.ru/post/154187/ works. And I don't see much difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in the example they use

```
FCGX_InitRequest(&request, 0, 0);
```

while the second argument must be socket id. Nice examples, guys.

Comment: The odd thing:
 FCGX_Init();
 FCGX_InitRequest(&request, 0, 0);

This worked for a while but stopped working ...

Comment: i guess socket id might just so happen to be zero in the past, but not now.

Comment: So what did you set the socket id to? I have been running it like the example for years, working fine Today I recompile the FCGI server for a new Ubuntu installation and I get -88 on the accept like you did.

Comment: result of FCGX_OpenSocket();

Comment: `0` is perfectly valid as the second argument to FCGX_InitRequest, which is the file number for STDIN by default. If you want to open a UNIX domain socket for instance, call `FCGX_OpenSocket` with the `path` of the socket file and the `backlog` (e.g. 128). It returns the file number that can be used instead when calling FCGX_InitRequest.

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle fastCGI calls using Unix sockets, as below:

```
    int socketId = FCGX_OpenSocket("/tmp/fcgi.sock", SOMAXCONN);
    if (socketId < 0) {
            std::cerr << "Error opening socket" << std::endl;
            return 1;
    }

    FCGX_Init();
    FCGX_Request request;

    FCGX_InitRequest(&request, socketId, 0);
    while (FCGX_Accept_r(&request) == 0) {
    // Handle request
    }
```

Comment: Haven't been here for a while. I'm going to check your solution just in case and hopefully mark it as accepted